# Optimisation of a Clean string function

Tags: python, regex, r, replace

So I have a clean string function in Python and also in R. However in Python it seems to run much much slower - Around 2-3x the time taken in R.

So I was wondering if anyone had any ways to optimise it. I have attempted to pin point the slowness and find it maybe the use of the re library, but I don't see a way around not using it. If anyone could please point me in the right direction of how to make it faster, that would be great.

Imports required:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
import string
import numpy as np

with open('input_data/stopwords.txt', 'rb') as f:
    stopwords= [line.strip() for line in f]
stopwords = r'\b(' + '|'.join(stopwords) + r')\b'
protwords = [line.strip() for line in open("input_data/protwords.txt", 'r')]
exceptions = [line.strip() for line in open("input_data/exceptions.txt", 'r')]
```

The main function is as follows:

```
def cleanTitle(title):
    length = len(title)
    title = title.decode('windows-1252')
    title = title.encode('utf-8','replace')
    title = title.lower()
    if '&#' in title:
        title = replaceHTML(title)

    title = trimWhitespace(title, False)
    title = title.translate(string.maketrans("","") ,string.punctuation)
    title = replaceSynonyms(title)
    title = re.sub(stopwords,'', title)
    titleWords = set(title.split())

    stemmedWords = []
    for word in titleWords:
        if word.isalpha():
            if not word in protwords:
                word =  stemWord(word)
            if word:    
                stemmedWords.append(word)

    title = ' '.join(list(set(stemmedWords)))
    return str(title)
```

Helper functions are as follows:

```
# STEMMER
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")

def stemWord(word):
    stemedWord = None
    try:
        stemedWord = stemmer.stem(word)
    except:
        print 'cannot stem'
    return stemedWord

# SYNONYMS
with open('input_data/synonyms.txt', 'rb') as f:
    synonyms = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]

def replaceSynonyms(title):
    for words in synonyms:
        pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(words) + r')\b')
        title = pattern.sub( words[0], title)
    return title

# HTML CODE REMOVER
htmlCodes = pd.read_csv('input_data/html_codes.csv',sep=',',header=0, na_values=[' '])

with open('input_data/synonyms.txt', 'rb') as f:
    codes = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f] 

def replaceHTML(title):
    for name, row in htmlCodes.iterrows():
        friend = row['friendly']
        display = re.escape(str(row['display']))
        hexC = row['hex']

        if isinstance(display, str):
            title = re.sub(hexC, display  ,title)
        if isinstance(friend, str):
            title = re.sub(friend,display, title)

    title = re.sub("&.{1,6};|<.{1,7}>", "", title)
    return title
```

Unfortunately I wont be able to put up the data .csv files themselves, for stopword, protwords, synonyms, exceptions, but it should be easy enough! The format of the tricker file, being html_codes.csv, is in the format:

```
display     friendly       hex
__________________________________
                        &#x09;
                        &#x10;
                        &#x20;
!                       &#x21;
"           &quot;      &#x22;
#                       &#x23;
```

EDIT: I have now tried re2 as a replacement for re -> increased time

Comment: You should use a line oriented profiler to find the hot spot in your code.

Comment: @dstromberg Thanks - that is great advice! My issue now is really interpreting the results...Also by the looks of it, removeSynonms and removeHTML is taking the longest time, but to find out these do you then need to run the profiler on separate function files?

Comment: Robert Kern's line_profiler can pinpoint which line(s) have trouble.  Apparently there are patches available that make it work with CPython 3.x if you need that.

Comment: Thanks very much! I pinpointed the problem and now I can do 10k string cleans in 2.64499497414 and R does it in 149.034! (Before I in Python I had it at 383.784031868)